# Chrome session data lost

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, oauth

I'm having problems with Chrome and PHP Sessions.
I'm building an OAuth2 server that is going to be used for my organization and the OAuth2 part is working perfectly but when I try to implement a simple login before OAuth2 authorization request the PHP Session is reset everytime i refresh a page on Chrome only (already tested with Firefox, Safari and Edge).

The favicon is **NOT** missing since the file is in the root (random favicon found on the web since my favicon is not ready yet, no copyright infringement intended).

My PHP OAuth2 authorize.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';

$request = OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = new OAuth2\Response();

if (!$server->validateAuthorizeRequest($request, $response)) {
    $response->send();
    die;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user'])){
    $link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    echo "<script>window.location.href = \"login.php?next=".urlencode($link)."\";</script>";
    die('');
}
if (empty($_POST)) {
  exit('
<form method="post">
  <label>Do You Authorize TestClient?</label><br />
  <input type="submit" name="authorized" value="yes">
  <input type="submit" name="authorized" value="no">
</form>');
}
$is_authorized = ($_POST['authorized'] === 'yes');
$server->handleAuthorizeRequest($request, $response, $is_authorized);
$response->send();
```

My login.php:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user'])){
        if(empty($_POST)){
?>
<form method="post">
  <label>Do You Want To Login To TestClient?</label><br />
  <input type="submit" name="authorized2" value="yes">
  <input type="submit" name="authorized2" value="no">
</form>
<?php
        }else{
            $_SESSION['logged_in_user'] = true;
            echo "<script>window.location.href = \"".urldecode($_GET['next'])."\";</script>";
            die('');
        }
    }else{echo "<script>window.location.href = \"".urldecode($_GET['next'])."\";</script>";}
?>
```

As you can see is quite a simple code (I'll implement the real db fetch login later).

The PHP library I'm using for OAuth2 is the one from bshaffer that you can find on github, the "server.php" file is the one you can find in the library cookbook.

My php.ini values for session :
[php.ini session values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LIs8.png)

If anyone wants to try access, I'm doing my tests via Google OAuth 2.0 Playground.

The setup values for playground :
[playground setup values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmHwd.png)

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

**EDIT 1** : The PHP version I've installed is 7.1.8 as FPM service over ISPConfig 3.1.6

Comment: i don't see session_start at the top of your example pages [session basics](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: if you see my php.ini : "session.auto_start" => "On"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I've found the problem...memcache.
For some unknown reason memcache and sessions are not to work together on my PHP installation. Other caching systems are ok, but if I activate memcache sessions are not working in Chrome only.

- PHP 7.1.8
- Memcache 3.0.9-dev
- Memcached 3.0.3

I've also tried with Memcache 3.0.8 (stable) but the result doesn't change...sessions are ok but not in Chrome that loses session every page reload.